# Does NDK strip debug info?

Tags: linux, linker, android-ndk, gdb, debug-symbols

I'm building an NDK shared library with a static library (.a) as one of the inputs. The static library has debug info in GDB format. Does the debug info end up in the final .SO? How can I check?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it does. The final step of NDK build is copying the `.so` file from `obj` directory to `lib`, stripping the symbols on the way. You can see how much smaller the file gets in `lib/armeabi`.

Comment: Is keeping symbols somewhere aside an option?

Comment: You can use the `obj/` copy for debugging.

Comment: Not sure how exactly (I'm after interpreting runtime crashes on user devices), but thanks for the hint.

Comment: @AlexCohn how do you do this? if I copy it from obj to libs, then run, it just gets a new small version again put in the lib folder. And will this give me a readable call stack during a seg fault?

Comment: @weston: please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218507/ndk-stack-not-working