# Android NDK APP_BUILD_SCRIPT Error

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk

I'm new to Android NDK and i've faced this error that

> "APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to C:\abc\xyz/jni/Android.mk"

I searched all the questions wasn't able to find the answer. However by just goofing around i was able to generate the jni library.

I did the following changes

1) I added a user variable APP_BUILD_SCRIPT which points to my project's Android.mk. eg.

> C:\abc\src\jni\Android.mk

2) I added another user variable NDK_PROJECT_PATH to the src folder of my project. eg.

> C:\abc\src

This src folder will have a folder named jni which contains my Native.c file and Android.mk.

And when I compiled, I saw a libs folder containing armeabi\lib_filename.so

However now when I run the program it throws an error "UnsatisfiedLinkError"
How do I tackle this?

Also for each project I have to change my user variables can anyone tell me a way to solve these issues.

**Information**:

I followed this example: [How to use NDK in android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359720/how-to-use-ndk-in-android-project)

Just add my steps to it and you should be able to generate .so file.